# Is there a website or resource which has complete comparions of EJBs versions

Tags: java, ejb

I am looking for a website/blog or a resource online which lists the comparison of all the versions of EJB till date. For example, from EJB 2.0 to EJB 3.1 and has column wise comparison of what was added to the newer version of EJB.

Please respond, your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJB 3.x is quite different and much simpler in use than EJB 2.x. I don't think you wil find table-like comparison for its featires because there are so many changes.

Google gives these links:

http://www.ucertify.com/article/differences-between-ejb-21-and-ejb-30.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.jee5.doc/topics/cejb3vejb21.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did google before asking the question, i am looking for another answers, or a complete comprehensive comparison.